# bootstrapvalidator enable multi submit

Tags: jquery

I read a lot and many asking for preventing the form re-submission and bootstrapvalidator do a good job on this.

But for a reason I need the submit button to be even after form submission.

How to I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#loginForm').bootstrapValidator('disableSubmitButtons', false);